# How to improve the run time for this code regarding formula updating?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulty with the run time of this code, it takes about 7 minutes to complete all the formulas for over 20,000 rows...is there any alterations to make this run faster?

```
 With Sheets("Rec")
 .Range("A6:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],RC[2],RC[3],RC[4],RC[5],RC[6],RC[7],RC[8])"
 .Range("J6:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(CDGL!C[-9],Rec!RC[-9],CDGL!C[29])"
 .Range("K6:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(STS!C[-9],Rec!RC[-10],STS!C[28])"
 .Range("L6:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
 .Range("M6:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(CDGL!C[-12],Rec!RC[-12],CDGL!C[30])"
 .Range("N6:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(STS!C[-12],Rec!RC[-13],STS!C[26])"
 .Range("O6:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to turn automatic calculation Off, then turn it back on (once the codes completes). I would also set the screenupdating to false... something like this, but at the beginning of your code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Sheets("Rec")
 .Range("A6:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],RC[2],RC[3],RC[4],RC[5],RC[6],RC[7],RC[8])"
 .Range("J6:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(CDGL!C[-9],Rec!RC[-9],CDGL!C[29])"
 .Range("K6:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(STS!C[-9],Rec!RC[-10],STS!C[28])"
 .Range("L6:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
 .Range("M6:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(CDGL!C[-12],Rec!RC[-12],CDGL!C[30])"
 .Range("N6:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(STS!C[-12],Rec!RC[-13],STS!C[26])"
 .Range("O6:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
 End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```